# What is the rep bubble next to my top tag?

Tags: support, tags, reputation, profile-page

In the "Summary" box on my profile on Server Fault, I see a rep bubble with +20 next to my top tag:

[image: Screen shot of the Summary box]

What does this number signify?

I tried to search across MSE and MSO but I could not find anything specific about the top tag (most questions I could find are about the top tags, plural, from the "Tags" tab on my profile) or in particular about any reputation indicator next to it.

Comment: Is that not just the rep gain for that tag from two up-votes you received on March 20?

Comment: I suggest adding [a freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#comment1217748_19775) (not a joke).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically what @[Elements in Space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/938841/elements-in-space) said in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388628/what-is-the-rep-bubble-next-to-my-top-tag#comment1295834_388628). Here's a screenshot from my profile:
[image]

Hovering over the bubble displays the message 'Reputation gained on this tag since your last visit to the reputation tab.'

(If you switch to tracking your next tag badge, the bubble disappears.)

Comment: Thanks. The tooltip is obviously not available on mobile.

Comment: @tripleee I can't confirm about top tag rep, but on all rep tooltip is [available for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLW6z.jpg) on iPad after the tapping on it.